# Use of Past Perfect if an interlocutor doesn't know about a moment in the past

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, past-tense, past-perfect

We use Past Perfect to speak about actions before some moment in the past.

1. What if my speaking partner doesn't know about a moment in the past?

> I had done everything.

(I don't mention it, but in the mind I mean, I had done before some moment, which I know).

2. What if i don't mention an moment, but it's obvious?

> I had written all documents.

(It can be either obvious or unobvious, that I had written all documents before a deadline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first point to understand is that "I had done everything." is only a sentence if there is an understood point of past time, stated or implicit, in the conversation or paragraph.  Otherwise it  is just a fragment.  If someone enters a room of complete strangers and says: "I had done everything.", these people would wonder whether the person had taken leave of their senses.  As you yourself point out, there has to be some context, stated or implied.  Something like

> I just got fired for not completing my tasks, but I had done everything.

Or, I could come into the room carrying the fatal cardboard box of instant dismissal, and say:

> I had done everything.

As OP states, there is then an obviously implied temporal context involving something before he got fired and so makes sense of the pluperfect tense.

Comment: It looks like '[sentence] fragment' is ill- (variously-)defined, just as 'sentence' is. Some sources include independent clauses not getting a complete thought (in context) across while others require a purely syntactic definition (a string missing a subject / finite verb).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth.  Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your interlocutor doesn't need to know anything about the remote past to understand that you are referring to a less remote past time in relation to a more remote past time when you use the past perfect.

The past perfect can introduce by implication a time-frame in the past that is subsequent to some other older events.

You could open an account like this:

> I had put on my boots, had donned my raincoat, and had remembered to bring my umbrella.

The implicit reference is to some moment *after* those earlier preparations for rain.  That sentence might be followed with something like this:

> But when I reached into my pocket to take out my wallet, my pocket was empty. In my mind's eye, I could see it sitting on the shelf near the front door, placed there so I wouldn't forget it.